# How to invoke parent component with HTML select in Angular 1.5

Tags: angularjs

I have a root component that inputs items to a child component:

```
angular.module('demoApp', ['listing'])
.component('smartComponent', {
  templateUrl: 'smartComponent.template.html',
    controller: function() {
      var self = this;

      self.items = [{
        id: 1,
        text: 'item1'
      }, {
        id: 2,
        text: 'item2'
      }];

      self.selectItem = function(item) {
        console.log('Selected item: ' + JSON.stringify(item));  
      };

    }
})
```

There is one-way binding to the items for the child component:

```
angular.module('listing', [])
.component('listing', {
  templateUrl: 'listing.template.html',
  bindings: {
    items: '<',
    onSelect: '&'
  }
```

});

I can easily handle clicks to select an item with `ng-click`. But I am not sure how to handle a `select` drop-down.

```
<div class="form-group">
<select id="test" class="form-control" ng-change="$ctrl.onSelect({item: item})" ng-model="$ctrl.itemId" ng-options="item.id as item.text for item in $ctrl.items track by item.id" required>
    <option value="">---Please select---</option>
</select>
```

Here is a plunker with a working ng-click, and non-working select: http://plnkr.co/edit/lQAhsqvsyjwCRhvkhSuS?p=preview

How do I get to pass an item to the parent component with `select`? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get the results you were getting with the `ng-click` by changing the `ng-options` and `ng-model` values in `listing.template.html` from your plunk.

You had this:

```
  <select id="test" 
          class="form-control" 
          ng-change="$ctrl.onSelect({item: item})" 
          ng-model="$ctrl.itemId" 
          ng-options="item.id as item.text for item in $ctrl.items track by item.id" 
          required>
```

I got it to work by changing it to this:

```
  <select id="test" 
          class="form-control" 
          ng-change="$ctrl.onSelect({item: $ctrl.item})" 
          ng-model="$ctrl.item" 
          ng-options="item.text for item in $ctrl.items" 
          required>
```

`item` isn't actually a value available on the $scope, as it could only available in the `option` children.  But if you use the same value for `ng-model` as you do for the parameter you are passing into `onSelect`, the selected value will be available to you.  I know that I removed a lot of the clauses you were using in the `ng-options`, but hopefully this will get you back on track.